# wordpress api json malformed- jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress, api

I have to make a way to show my posts with the API, and I have a problem with malformed json because some html inside the content part that returns the API.

jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://bytto.com/wp-json/posts?type[name]=package&filter[category]=eco-tours-petate",
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

To see the json just copy and paste the next url in chrome or firefox:

http://bytto.com/wp-json/posts?type[name]=package&filter[category]=eco-tours-petate

I evaluate the response in http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and said:

```
Error:Invalid characters found.
```

I look at it and it is on content node and excerpt node that the json fails.

If I return this as a plain text with: `dataType: "text"` it comes and what I like to do is to clean up the text to make it json.

Comment: Can you share your JSON?

Comment: sure, just copy and paste this url in chrome or firefox: http://bytto.com/wp-json/posts?type[name]=package&filter[category]=eco-tours-petate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was do the next simple thing: data=(data.replace(/\>/g , ">"));

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "http://bytto.com/wp-json/posts?type[name]=package&filter[category]=eco-tours-petate",
    success: function(data){


      data=(data.replace(/\\>/g , ">"));
      data = $.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(data);


  }
});
```

That do the job to make my string to a correct json format.

Thanks @vard!
Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems thats it's the line break in the HTML parts of your JSON that make the parser fail. Indeed, `<br \>` should be `<br \/>`.

This should clean the JSON before parsing it:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "http://bytto.com/wp-json/posts?type[name]=package&filter[category]=eco-tours-petate",
    success: function(data){
        data = data.replace('<br \>', '<br \/>');
        data = data.replace(/(?!\\)(\/)/, '\/');
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: may be a funcion to replace the \ for \/ will do the job? or replacing <br \> for <br \/>

Comment: no :( malformed again.  Theres a general function to escape all bad characters that must be escaped in JSON data to avoid any problems?

Comment: Well it should be done on API side. There is few things in HTML that can make a JSON parser break: a non escaped forward slash (/), a non escaped quote or even no space before slash for a self closing tag. You should check for all those thing and use `replace` to clean up the data.

Comment: or a way that "content" and  "excerpt" dont comes from wordpress api

Comment: I updated my answer with a more generic regex wich should fix the forward slash issues. Didn't had time to test but it should work.